# JSON-авторизация на сайте через C#

Tags: c#, json, post

Как пройти авторизацию на сайте через подобный запрос?
Токен с сайта выдернул, не знаю как составить такой запрос.
Вот фрагменты запроса из GoogleChrome.

```
Request URL:https://url/auth/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Content-Type:application/json

Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data
tkn:d5e2ecaf42f9423f7d3e87b72718838d
user_email:login
user_password:password
submitted:1
Fields[]:tkn
Fields[]:user_email
Fields[]:user_password
Fields[]:submitted
_ajax:1

Source:
tkn=d5e2ecaf42f9423f7d3e87b72718838d&user_email=login&user_password=password&submitted=1&Fields%5B%5D=tkn&Fields%5B%5D=user_email&Fields%5B%5D=user_password&Fields%5B%5D=submitted&_ajax=1
```

Comment: А что, у сайта нет API, и он разрешает доступ роботам?

Comment: Работа с API не устраивает. Функционала много использовать не собираюсь, поэтому устроят обычные запросы.

Comment: А не через API скорее всего неподдерживаемый сценарий.